# How to get the sizes of different Azure Blob Container inside Azure Storage Account on Grafana

Tags: azure-blob-storage, grafana, azure-storage-account, azure-monitor, grafana-dashboard

I have a use case in which I have a Storage Account in Azure which contains multiple containers, and inside those multiple containers, I have multiple folders in which data keeps on storing.
I have Grafana, and connected Azure Monitor datasource to get some insights from Azure.

```
# Representation of the usecase:

- My Storage Account
--- Container 1
    ---- Folder 1
    ---- Folder 2
    ---- Folder 3
--- Container 2
    ---- Folder 1
    ---- Folder 2
    ---- Folder 3

## Requirement: Need to find different sizes of below multiple folders & visualise them on Grafana.
```

My requirement is to get some visualisation on Grafana, of the data stored inside those multiple folders in different containers on Azure Storage Account.

I did found some OpenSource dashboards mentioned, which only shows overall storage which the storage account is consuming.
([Dashboard1](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/9962-microsoft-azure-storage/)
[Dashboard2](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/14469-azure-insights-storage-accounts/))

But in my use case, I want to do it on more granular level.

1. Do we have such dashboards which can show folder/container wise data consumption?
2. I want to know from Azure/Grafana experts, Is it possible to fetch container wise properties (like size etc) data on such granular level with Grafana?
3. Always open for your suggestions, if you suggest any other approach which fits the requirement.